# Text Not Aligning Properly - font-size issue?

Tags: css

I'm trying to align text on top of an image in such a way that it remains aligned even if the underlying image is increased/decreased in size. I'm using px values that were taken from Photoshop measurements.

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/dXNgx/. The word "For" is being overlaid on the image. It measures 20px in height, but when placed on the image, `font-size: 20px;` results in a "For" that is smaller than the underlying image. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the div.layer outside of the #page1 as otherwise -moz-transform:scale(.5); is applied to it.

```
<a href="#" id="zoom_in">Zoom In +</a> | <a href="#" id="zoom_out">Zoom Out -</a>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="-moz-transform:scale(.5); -moz-transform-origin:left top;position:absolute;" class="page" id="page1">
        <div class="layer" style="z-index:1;">
            <img src="http://cobalt.xtracta.com/images/image.jpg" style="width:2480px; height:3508px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="z-index:2;">
        <div style="font-size: 20px; position:absolute; color:#F00; top: 1550px; left: 306px;">For</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dXNgx/2/

Comment: yes, the 20px looks about the right size now. However, the "For" is no longer plotted correctly. The properties `top: 1550px; left: 306px;` should be about right. Why did the "For" move?

Comment: before the absolute positioned div had no parent with position relational. This made the abs pos div be absolute in relation to the body. both div.layer are now absolute positioned in relation to the main div instead. depending on the size of your screen this may give different results but if you adjust the position now it will work with any screen size.